# Longer password salts stored locally or shorted password salts not stored locally?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have an offline application that encrypts local file (using aes-356-gcm) and it uses scrypt for password hashing (both from the node.js crypto library). Because the application is offline I can't prevent the user from being locked out after x attempts like a web app.

My question: Is it more secure to use a really long salt that is shared between all instances of the application, or would it be better to ask the user to remember a 6-8 byte salt that is not stored anywhere?

My initial thought would be that the 4-8+ byte salt that is not stored in a config file would be more secure because it would act almost as a second password. On the other hand, a 32bit salt is quite short (but would it even be considered a salt in this case?).

My current implementation uses a default hash for if the user just doesn't want to worry about remembering another pass phrase. Then, they can either specify their own salt or have a random one generated based on the number of bytes they want the length to be. The salt is not stored anywhere in any type of config file or anything along those lines.

The other idea I had was to generate a longer salt and prepend it to each encrypted file. Would this be overkill?

- I also want to say: This is not an application that will be used in production. I am simply a student who's trying to learn on a personal app. I've already received all the "you shouldn't be implementing this if you don't know anything about encryption" comments. I understand your concern so let me just put it to rest now.

Comment: Those are not your only two options. You can also generate a random salt every time you encrypt and store that salt together with the ciphertext. That's what virtually everyone else does. Take a look at a passphrase protected (i.e. encrypted) SSH key, for instance; the DEK-Info header contains the salt.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to let the user remember a salt or part of the salt. The salt is supposed to protect against rainbow tables. Instead you should probably require users to use long passwords (through instruction or verification) and increase the work factor of scrypt so that brute forcing will be infeasible.

Comment: @Peter I also had this idea, but this would require the user either enters the password for each encrypted file or I would have to store the plain text password since I would have to run the password and salt through scrypt for each file. Rather what I want is to have one password and salt for all the files within a directory.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Would there be benefit to allowing the user to enter two passwords. First (as an option but not required), I would take the default salt and second password provided, run it through scrypt, turn the results into a hex string and use that as the salt for hashing the first password. This would allow me to make sure that users with the same password1 aren't showing the same resulting password hash.

And yes, absolutely, like you mentioned a long password is also key. This is more as an optional added element.

Comment: No, this would not be better. Since it is local, a potential attacker has the code and is able to reverse engineer your hashing scheme. If you want to provide an option for more security-minded users, tell them to use longer and more complex passwords. Also, since this is local code, an attacker could just access the data directly if you haven't encrypted it.